# Codeigniter Where with AND

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to build a query with codeigniter like this.

> SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE machine=$var AND date BETWEEN '$today' AND
>   '$oneMonthAgo'

here my modal

```
public function getHistory($machine)
    {
    $today = date('Y-m-d');

    $month=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 month"));
    $query = $this->db->from('table')->where('machine', $machine)->where("date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$month'")->get();

        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            return $query->row();
        }
    }
```

I been trying but I don't get results
plus: with this line  can calculate the date a month ago

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$month=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 month"));
```

sorry my english xP

Comment: why not use `date < '$today' AND date > '$month'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the below code:-

```
public function getHistory($machine)
{
    $today = date('Y-m-d');
    $query = $this->db->from('table')
             ->where('machine', $machine)
             ->where('date >=', (NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH))
             ->get();
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
      return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
$this->db->query(your query);
```

like.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE machine=$var AND date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$oneMonthAgo'";
$this->db->query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getHistory($machine)
{
$today = date('Y-m-d');

$month=date('Y-m-d',strtotime("-1 month"));
$query = $this->db->from('table')->where("machine= '$machine' AND date BETWEEN '$today' AND '$month'")->get();

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        return $query->row();
    }
}
```

Hope it works...

Answer (score 0):

try this. i hope it will help you.

```
return $this->db->where("machine = '" . $machine . "' AND date >= '" . $today . "' AND date <= '" . $$month . "'")->get('table')->result_array();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
public function getHistory($machine)
{
    $today = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'));

    $query = $this->db
      ->where('machine', $machine)
      ->where('DATE(date) <=', $today)
      ->where('DATE(date) >=', $month)
      ->get('table');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
      return $query->result();
    }
}
```

Ref: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

**Custom Query**

```
public function getHistory($machine)
{
    $today = date('Y-m-d'); 
    $month = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('-1 month'));

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE machine={$var} AND date BETWEEN {$today} AND {$oneMonthAgo}"
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
      return $query->result();
    }
}
```